# Sorry — your last action could not be completed

Tags: paypal

I have confusion, that I have integrated recurring payment system.

It was working well before, 3 days. 
Form 2 days I am getting error

> Sorry — your last action could not be completed
>   When I am trying to login.

It login successfully but now shows the payment confirmation page.

What should be the issue?

I am using sandbox for now.

Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/My-account-settings-Archive/Sorry-your-last-action-could-not-be-completed/td-p/154782

Comment: Still not working any useful help plz.

Answer (score 0):

please check or do the following

1. Use a *separate browser* page for logging into sandbox.paypal.com as you stated you are trying to 'login'
2. I have noticed periodically that sandbox.paypal.com loads my live credentials when a previous paypal.com session was activated; an apparent cookie issue
3. If you have a password / user id client like fast pass, etc; make sure to verify the password that's injected into the fields in your options of the pw/user ID client

Please take note as I am replying to:

Sorry — your last action could not be completed When I am trying to login <-- Not to recurring payments system not working as it appears that these are 2 different issues. If not, please clarify for me